# Cannot read property 'apply ' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the .apply-method. So, I created the following code:

```
var o = new Object();
o.method = function(x, y) {
  return x + y
};

o.method = (function(original) {
  return function(x, y) {
    var a = 'A';
    var b = 'B';
    var result = original.apply(this, [a, b]);
    return result;
  }
})(o.method);

console.log(o.method(1, 2));
```

I thought that the last open and close parentheses could be empty and so the method o.method is invoked automatically. But with empty parentheses

```
o.method = (function(original) {
  return function(x, y) {
    var a = 'A';
    var b = 'B';
    var result = original.apply(this, [a, b]);
    return result;
  }
})();

o.method(1, 2);
```

I get the following error:
Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Can someone please explain me why?

Kind regards
Henning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: You aren't passing a parameter to the outer function.

Comment: @SLaks: Sorry, i have updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke the function `function(original) {}` you return a the function `function(x, y) {}` and you create a closure over the parameter `original`. So the code inside of the `function(x, y) {}` has allways access to what ever you passed to `function(original) {}`

With:

```
o.method = (function(original) {
  return function(x, y) {
    // ... 
  }
})(o.method);
```

You assign that returned `function(x, y) {}` function having a closure over `original` to `o.method` passing the original `o.method` as argument.

If you now write `o.method(1,2)`  you call that returned `function(x, y) {}`.

If you called that `function(original) {}` with no argument `(function(original) {})()` then  `original` is `undefined` and `original.apply` would result in your posted error.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. So ... with the last both parantheses I define the argument for the parameter original?

Answer (score 1):

With some change your code is correct:

```
var o = new Object();
o.method2 = function(x,y){return x+y};

o.method = (function (original){
    return function(x,y){
            var result = original.call(this, x,y);
        return result;
    }
})(o.method2);
```

Also for test and run:

```
o.method(2,3)
```

Result is 5

Also with Apply:

```
var o = new Object();
o.method2 = function(x,y){return x+y};

o.method = (function (original){
    return function(x,y){
            var result = original.apply(this, [x,y]);
        return result;
    }
})(o.method2);
```

Then test:

```
o.method(2,3)
```

Result is 5

For more information about the usage of call() and apply() you can read this article: 
http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/invoking-javascript-functions-with-call-and-apply.html